# Factorising and substrings

Tags: r, stringr

I have tried to extract a substring from a column of strings from a dataset and then I tried to factorise it. However, it still shows me repetition of the same category, e.g. there should only be one Container category but there are multiple Container categories.

For example, this is one of the strings in the column:

```
link=Storing and Release Orders > Storing Order : Enquire;type=URL;url=https://wwwsg.portnet.com/SOROWeb/com/pn2/soro/web/EnquireSO/EnquireSOController.jpf;webenv=Internet (Secondary);
```

and I would like to extract the part ***Storing and Release Orders*** from the string.

I tried something like this:

```
mutate(category = str_sub(USERDATA, 6)) %>%

mutate(category = str_trim(str_replace(category, ">.*", "")))
```

and then I wanted to factorise this column, but I get repetitions of the same category.

This is a sample dataset I'm using
[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please share a sample data with `?dput` and paste the code inside the question instead of an external image? In this way it will be easier for other people to help you. Thank you!

Comment: ok i have edited it @Ric S

Comment: Please check my edit, not sure if the "*" are part of the line

Comment: @eunji could you also post a sample data of your dataframe with `dput(combined)`? (in the code you pasted your dataset was named `combined` if I'm not wrong)

Comment: I have added an image @Ric S

Comment: @eunji Can't you use the function `dput`? With an image it is impossible to work with that sample data

Answer (score 0):

I write this answer as there is not enough space in the comment section to show everything. I will edit/delete it in case you still have problems and the answer changes consequently.

I tried to create a sample dataset from your image:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

set.seed(1)
sample_data <- c(
  "link=Storing and Release Orders > Storing Order : Enquire;type=URL;url=https://wwwsg.portnet.com/SOROWeb/com/pn2/soro/web/EnquireSO/EnquireSOController.jpf;webenv=Internet (Secondary);",
  "link=Pregate Services > Storing Order : Enquire;type=URL;url=https://wwwsg.portnet.com/SOROWeb/com/pn2/soro/web/EnquireSO/EnquireSOController.jpf;webenv=Internet (Secondary);",
  "link=Delivery Order > Storing Order : Enquire;type=URL;url=https://wwwsg.portnet.com/SOROWeb/com/pn2/soro/web/EnquireSO/EnquireSOController.jpf;webenv=Internet (Secondary);",
  "link=Electronic Shipping Note > Storing Order : Enquire;type=URL;url=https://wwwsg.portnet.com/SOROWeb/com/pn2/soro/web/EnquireSO/EnquireSOController.jpf;webenv=Internet (Secondary);",
  "link=Vessel > Storing Order : Enquire;type=URL;url=https://wwwsg.portnet.com/SOROWeb/com/pn2/soro/web/EnquireSO/EnquireSOController.jpf;webenv=Internet (Secondary);"
)

df <- data.frame(
  USERDATA = sample(sample_data, 30, replace = TRUE)
)
```

I then used your same code and factorised the variable `category` using `as.factor`

```
cats <- df %>% 
  mutate(category = str_sub(USERDATA, 6)) %>%
  mutate(category = str_trim(str_replace(category, ">.*", ""))) %>% 
  mutate(category = as.factor(category))
```

and I obtained a `factor` variable with 5 levels (as should be expected)

```
cats$category
 [1] Storing and Release Orders Electronic Shipping Note   Storing and Release Orders Pregate Services           Vessel                     Delivery Order            
 [7] Pregate Services           Delivery Order             Delivery Order             Storing and Release Orders Vessel                     Vessel                    
[13] Pregate Services           Pregate Services           Storing and Release Orders Vessel                     Vessel                     Storing and Release Orders
[19] Storing and Release Orders Vessel                     Vessel                     Pregate Services           Pregate Services           Storing and Release Orders
[25] Electronic Shipping Note   Storing and Release Orders Electronic Shipping Note   Delivery Order             Pregate Services           Pregate Services          
Levels: Delivery Order Electronic Shipping Note Pregate Services Storing and Release Orders Vessel

nlevels(cats$category)
[1] 5

levels(cats$category)
[1] "Delivery Order"             "Electronic Shipping Note"   "Pregate Services"           "Storing and Release Orders" "Vessel"
```

So everything should be fine, in this case I have a `factor` of length 30 with 5 levels. Is this what you would expect?

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted to get, however, I do not know why I get duplicates when I run it. Would it be possible to send you the dataset?

Comment: Use `dput(name_of_your_dataframe)` and post the output inside your question, so that I can copy and paste it in my local computer. Anyway, do you get duplicates when you run `levels(cats$category)` too?